# Naming a Workbook

Tags: vba

So 
`Workbooks.Open("D:\CE\2019\2019 Dump.xlsb")` 
works, but

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("D:\CE\2019\2019 Dump.xlsb")
```

Returns an error `Subscript out of bounds`

Why?

Comment: When a workbook is already open you just use `Workbooks("Dump.xlsb")`

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks collection stores name (of open Workbooks) without path as index. With Fullpath no wb of that name is opened -> no item with that index is found -> causing Subscript out of bounds

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\CE\2019\2019 Dump.xlsb")
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("2019 Dump.xlsb")
Dim wb3 As Workbook
Set wb3 = Workbooks("not an opened wb") 'error here as not in collection
Dim wb4 As Workbook
Set wb4 = Workbooks.Item("not n opened wb") 'Workbooks("not n opened wb") is short for  Workbooks.Item("not n opened wb") still error here as not in collection
```

To clearify: `Workbooks("wbname")` won't open a closed wb, as default (hidden) member of`Workbooks`is`_Default`property, what calls`.Item`(as it's a collection)
, not`.Open`.